# best way to remove create an object from image

Tags: modeling

Good day,

I know that this is probably a very simple question, but I have been looking and I have not found the exact answer to my issue.

I have this image and what I would like to do is extract the butterfly portion to be used.[image]

I have tried several options such as mirror modifiers on a plane and then outlining one side.  I have also tried the knife tool.  The mirror modification was the closest but then when I went to fill the face for extrusion it gave me a bunch of extra faces outside of the butterfly.

My next idea would take a cube and work it the same way as the plane, but at least this way I would have faces.  Is that the best solution or is there something else that I could try?

Answer (score 1):

You can import your image with *Images as Planes*, use the *Knife* tool to draw the edges along the shape:

[image]

Cut off the white part:

[image]

Give it a *Mirror* modifier (enable the *Clipping* option) and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Extrude and bevel if you want to give it thickness:

[image]

Another solution would be to import an image with a transparent background, in that case you won't have to cut with the knife, but you won't be able to extrude.